# How to find how much resources a particular command is consuming in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a python script i want to see how much network/ram/CPU the script is taking i want to see it so i can calculate my server specs

Any help will be appreciated.

I'm using screen to run my python script seperately.

[image: <code>top</code>]

I have tried `top/htop` but it does not even show me the PID.

Comment: `top` ISN't showing you the PID?  I've never seen that, can you give sample output from `top`?

Comment: `top` should return you with PID and it is the first column in your output image. `top -p <PID>` is the easiest way to get the info

Comment: apparently i have found /python3/ running with PID 836. It returns CPU and Memory but not network..